# Can’t update ICollection property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

The problem is when I try to update Master and Details Tables at the same time.
When call Post Edit Task the Details objects don´t appear.

The Edit View displays all Details rows correctly, but while debugging the Edit POST, Casas is empty

MODELS

```
 public partial class Modelo : IValidatableObject {
     public Modelo()    
     {
         Casas = new HashSet<Casa>();
     }

     public int Modeloid { get; set; }
     public string Modelo1 { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Casa> Casas { get; set; }//Don’t work to update
}

public partial class Casa   //  DETAIL TABLE
{
    public int Casaid { get; set; }
    public int Modeloid { get; set; }  // FK to Modelo
    public string Casa1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Modelo Modelo { get; set; }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
public class ModelosController : Controller

. . . . . . . . . 
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id,  Modelo modelo)
{
   if (id != modelo.Modeloid)
   {
       return NotFound();
   }
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
   //   Here modelo.Modelo1 has current modified value 
   //   but modelo.Casas.Count == 0
        _context.Update(modelo);  
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
}

// GET: Modelos/Edit
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    var modelo = await _context.Modelo
                       .AsNoTracking() 
                       .Include(m => m.Fotomodelos)
                       .Include(m => m.Casas)
                       .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Modeloid == id);
    if (modelo == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(modelo);
}
```

View EDIT.CSHTML

```
@using System.IO
@model Disponibilidad.Models.Modelo


<form asp-action="Edit">
  <div class="form-horizontal">
  <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
      <input type="hidden" asp-for="Modeloid" />
      <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Modelo1" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
           <input asp-for="Modelo1" class="form-control" />
           <span asp-validation-for="Modelo1" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      @{
       for (int i = 0; i < Model.Casas.Count; i++)
       {
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Casas.ElementAt(i).Modeloid"
                             value="@Model.Modeloid" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Casas.ElementAt(i).Casaid" />
        <div class="form-group">
         <label asp-for="@Model.Casas.ElementAt(i).Casa1" 
            class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
         <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="@Model.Casas.ElementAt(i).Casa1"      
               class="form-control" />    <!--  DISPLAY OK Detail rows -->  
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Casas.ElementAt(i).Casa1" 
              class="text-danger"></span>
         </div>
        </div>
       }
       }

       <div class="btn-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Save</button>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried isolating the problem to it's smallest reproducible unit? What I mean by this is that if your hypothesis is that ICollection is not behaving as you expected (presumably after reading the docs), then you should isolate this part of your logic such that you can ask the question without all the superflous code (making it much easier to help you).

If you do the above and find out that in fact ICollection does behave as it should in your circumstance then you can cross that off the list of problems and perhaps that would indicate a problem with MVC bind backs from the client?

Comment: Yes, I do. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: While i´m debugging Edit Post, the property  “Collection.count of Detail object” is = 0 (cero)   
Master Table   IS  class Modelo
Detail Table  IS  class Casa
I’m using VisualStudio 2017, EF Core and MVC Pattern
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check how it is getting rendered to output. To the binding occurs, the name of inputs should be similar to `modelo.propName`. I bet that you have to change Razor and add name and value properties manually instead of using the asp-for taghelper.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `for` cycle instead of `foreach` in Razor, the name of the properties doesn't get rendered correctly when using the default `asp-for` TagHelpers.

You can correct your example changing your razor form inputs as follow:

From:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Casas.ElementAt(i).Casaid" />
```

To:

```
<input type="hidden" name="modelo.Casas[@i].Casaid" value="@Model.Casas.ElementAt(i).Casaid" />
```

Comment: Thanks João  !!!   Using  [@i]   works!!!    Nevertheless  foreach fail for me..   I will use for statement and  [@i]    . 
Thanks again

Comment: You can look at the generated HTML with foreach and try to find the catch, but this will do the same... Glad to help!